# Multidimensional array to store three different data types?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a set of three values pairs that I want to store in an array, each value with different type.

`[string][int][double]` for storing things like `[John][12][40.025]` `[Amy][20][16000.411]` and I want to be able to retrieve the values by location. What container should I use?

I have looked through many answers but most of them were about two data types, and I don't know which one better suit my case.

Comment: You can use `std::tuple<string,int,double>`, and `get<N>` to access the Nth tuple element. You can store these tuples in an `array` or `vector`.

Comment: You could also use `std::vector<mystruct>` where mystuct is a class or struct that contains your 3 different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what classes are for:

```
struct data {
    std::string name;
    int         name_describing_this_variable;
    double      another_descriptive_name;
};
```

You can store instances of this class in an array:

```
data arr[] {
    {"John", 12, 40.025},
    {"Amy",  20, 16000.411},
};
```

Comment: How do I add a new set to the array?

Comment: @reddy Nothing can be added into an array. An array is initialised with the elements that it will have.

Comment: Using `std::vector<data>` instead of the array that has a fixed size at compile time can solve that.

Comment: What other container can I use that it can start out empty and I can add new set to it?

Comment: @drescherjm Okay I got it, this looks the easiest for me, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Use the class template `std::tuple` declared in the header `<tuple>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main() 
{
    std::tuple<std::string, int, double> t ={ "John", 12, 40.025 };

    std::cout << std::get<0>( t ) << ", "
              << std::get<1>( t ) << ", "
              << std::get<2>( t ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::get<std::string>( t ) << ", "
              << std::get<int>( t ) << ", "
              << std::get<double>( t ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
John, 12, 40.025
John, 12, 40.025
```

And you may use a container of elements with this type as for example an array because the listed types in the tuple are default constructible.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main() 
{
    std::tuple<std::string, int, double> t[1];

    t[0] = { "John", 12, 40.025 };

    std::cout << std::get<0>( t[0] ) << ", "
              << std::get<1>( t[0] ) << ", "
              << std::get<2>( t[0] ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::get<std::string>( t[0] ) << ", "
              << std::get<int>( t[0] ) << ", "
              << std::get<double>( t[0] ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

As an alternative you can define your own compound type (class or structure) that will contain sub-objects of required types.